# Debugging JavaScript/AngularJS in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs

Is it possible to set breakpoints and step through JavaScript code when working with an AngularJS application in Eclipse?

Which plugins are required on top of a standard Java EE installation?

I've installed the [AngularJS Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse), but I don't see how to use it for debugging.

Comment: I'd go for Batarang with chrome rather than IDE plugin

Comment: See https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252654